# При наведении на пункт меню показывать содержимое соответствующего блока

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Мне нужно чтобы при наведении на пункт меню показывался контент, который соответствует этому пункту но лежит в другом блоке standart-content. И как только ховер с пункта меня убирается - снова отображался стандартный контент . Не могу понять как это реализовать в jquery, очень надеюсь на вашу помощь.
Каждый .item-content соответствует пункту из меню, по задумке.
Примерную разметку набросал для понимания.

```css
.container {
width: 600px;
}
.container:after {
content: '';
display: block;
clear: both;
}
.container ul {
float: left;
width: 33.33%;
}
.container .content-ul {
width: 33.33%;
float: left;
}
.item-content {
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<ul>
<li><a href="">Пункт 1</a></li>
<li><a href="">Пункт 2</a></li>
<li><a href="">Пункт 3</a></li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><a href="">Пункт 4</a></li>
<li><a href="">Пункт 5</a></li>
<li><a href="">Пункт 6</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="content-ul">
<div class="standart-content">
Это стандартный контент
</div>
<div class="item-content">
Тут контент пункта 1
</div>
<div class="item-content">
Тут контент пункта 2
</div>
<div class="item-content">
Тут контент пункта 3
</div>
<div class="item-content">
Тут контент пункта 4
</div>
<div class="item-content">
Тут контент пункта 5
</div>
<div class="item-content">
Тут контент пункта 6
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: jquery tab......

Comment: Табы не работает на ховер

Comment: работают ......

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0v9nhxu3/1/

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#mouseover  официальный сайт

Comment: Спасибо. Только осталось не понятно как сделать чтобы если ховер не находится на пунктах меню то показывался стандартный контент.

Comment: а вот по этому поводу можете задать вопрос ! только этот удалите